# COUNT(*) работает не корретно

Tags: mysql, mysqli

ДД, хотел посчитать кол-во строк в таблице MySQL, но возникла странная проблема, при использовании запроса `` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `имя_таблицы` `` он выдаёт 3410 строк, хотя в таблице 3541 строка. Прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: используйте  SELECT COUNT(id), надеюсь у вас есть колонка с ID

Comment: Это - в консоли? и именно `COUNT(*)`? сказки какие-то... или имеются повреждения структуры...

Comment: Откуда вы знаете, что у вас в таблице 3541 строка?

Comment: @Arsen выдаёт теперь 3411...

Comment: @andreymal по колонке product_id

Comment: @MaksatSh я могу предположить, что у вас в таблице есть колонка с неким ID. и оно увеличивается с добавлением строк. и вот вы смотрите на последнее значение, которое равен 3541. но на самом деле, некоторые строки могут быть удалены. поэтому общее количество строк равен 3410

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а как выбрать последнюю строку таблицы?

Comment: @MaksatSh сортировать по убыванию колонку product_id и выбрать первое значение